# Atmega32u4 issue

Tags: atmega32u4, custom

I made a custom ATmega32u4 board for my project. Components came from clone of Arduino Pro Micro (with bootloader and code which I uploaded) from AliExpress. I soldered everything in to my board according to my schematic but the board doesn't work. I don't have any signal from that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qskHc.jpg

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Did you buy the atmega32u4 with bootloader? Which bootloader? How can you be sure that it has a bootloader? Even the arduino micro has a icsp header. Can you solder wires to it for a icsp header? Then you can upload a sketch with a programmer without bootloader. For example a sketch to toggle a pin or blink a led. After that you can try to use tx and rx with a extra usb-serial module to a computer. After that you can try the bootloader and try to upload a sketch.

Comment: Firstly i upload code to orginal board and everything was working. Then i soldered everything and i dont have any response from my custom board.

Comment: It's hard to tell from those pictures, but do you actually have any power going into VCC?

Comment: Now I've got into whatever EDA that is you're using I can see that no, it would appear not.  You actually have to provide power to the chip for it to successfully run...

Comment: I connect this wire and everything is working nice right now. Thanks for fast help ;)

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer, or post one of your own and mark it as accepted 48 hours later, as this will help other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

You have an error in your schematic.

You have used the net name VCC for your main power circuit. However your USB incoming power is labelled as +5V.

That means you have two separate nets - +5V with power on it, and VCC isolated from it entirely.

You need to connect those two nets together - name them both VCC or both +5V so they form a single net (easiest is to adopt VCC since you use that on other connections too).

To "fix" your current PCB you could connect a small wire from the cathode of D2 to pin 44 AVCC on the main chip which will bridge the two nets together.